# TypeError: window.swaggerUi is undefined + Springfox.js

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Randomly, i am getting below js error when i try to hit swagger-ui url for my Spring Rest service.

```
TypeError: window.swaggerUi is undefined

window.swaggerUi.headerView.trigger('update-swagger-ui', {
```

Most of the time, it is working fine and i am get response for all resources as expected.

Am i missing something? In swagger integration to Spring Rest service.

Version i am using is

```
    <swagger2.version>2.1.2</swagger2.version>
    <swagger-ui.version>2.3.1</swagger-ui.version>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I had the same issue and appeared because a securityInterceptor from the project was blocking the access to '/configuration/' referred from springfox.js.

If this is your case, try adding security exceptions for:

```
<security:http security="none" pattern="/v2/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/swagger-resources/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/swagger-ui.html"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/webjars/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/configuration/**"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Its works for me too. As you told for me it was blocking <security:http security="none" pattern="/v2/**"/> & <security:http security="none" pattern="/configuration/**"/>